# How to get Screenshot of Form with UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, screenshot

I want to get screenshot of MainForm of Application. I use following code for this.

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(MainForm.Width, MainForm.Height);
DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height));
pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
```

I have some user controls in MainForm. I can only get screenshot of MainForm using above code. I can't get screenshot of User Controls.

Can anybody suggest me how to get screenshot of Windows form with User Controls of the form?

Comment: Where do you execute this code? Inside the "main form"? Then what is `MainForm`? And why not `MainForm.DrawBitmap(..`?

Comment: You can use `Control.DrawToBitmap()`

Comment: Crystal ball says that you made the standard mistake of using CreateGraphics() in your user control.  Use the Paint event instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
private void CaptureForm()
{
    var bmp = new Bitmap(MainForm.Width, MainForm.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
    g.CopyFromScreen(MainForm.Location.X, MainForm.Location.Y, 0, 0,
                    MainForm.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    //Clipboard.SetImage(bmp);

    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```